# Is this busy waiting?

Tags: c, unix

Is this loop busy waiting, I would think the wait call takes care of that. If it is, how can it be fixed to not busy wait?

```
id = fork();
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    switch (id)
    {
             case 0:
                /* do stuff with child */
                exit(0);
             default:
             {
                 if (children>=3) {
                     int s;
                     wait(&s);
                     children--;
                 }
                 children++;
                 id = fork();
             }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wait` will cause the kernel to select other jobs that are not marked as blocked, so this isn't a case of busy-waiting. Also isn't switch a bit excessive for a fork(), why not use a simple if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, `wait` waits non-busy by handing over the CPU to the kernel until the child has exited.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really buys waiting (it doesn't check the status of the children in a loop; instead if blocks inside the `wait()` call).

Nonetheless, the code can hog the CPU depending on what happens in `do stuff with child`. That will look like busy waiting (CPU usage 100%) even though it's really several processes doing actual work.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, waiting on the death of a child (even inside a loop) would not be busy waiting.  OTOH you can get in real trouble if one or more of the child processes are compute intensive.  The compute-intensive children will always be ready to run and it is not guaranteed that the parent will get the CPU.